# Javascript window.location script keeps reloading

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'm trying to create a small web app where I update 2 paramaters in the URL via Javascript.

When I try `"window.location.search = 'scene.html?name=' + person + '&scene=' + readCookie("scene");"`

The page keeps reloading. I am trying to assign the current 'scene' parameter to an incremented value each time the page is 'loaded'.

Why is my page perpetually reloading with null and undefined values??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, I'm not following why you want to do something like that.

Whenever you change the window.location, the browser should go there. This is why you get the reload effect.. The only thing you can change from the location without reloading is the hash (#) part.

The other thing you could do, is to [manipulate the history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) of the browser with pushState (only latest versions support that) and change the url without reload (and also the server will not know about the change too) like: `window.history.pushState({},"","scene.html?name=123");`

Also note that since you change the search property of the location you shouldn't include the pathname (scene.html). So the correct way would be: `window.location.search = '?name=' + person + '&scene=' + readCookie("scene");`

Comment: Thanks for your answer - yes, not ideal. I thought I could use JS to navigate across a number of 'scene' pages, and update the scene cookie as I go. It was tricky to update the value each time on load without the constant reloading.

Answer (score 1):

When you update the `window.location` the browser will attempt to request the new URL that you've now set it to.

If you want to update the URL *without* the page being reloaded, you've got two options, either just update the [`hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location) (which is a part that can be added to the end of the URL and is preceded by a `#` character) which doesn't result in a page load and isn't sent to the server. Or you could look into using the [HTML5 pushState API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) which is only supported by newer browsers but offers more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks - I like this as a front end solution going forward but i've marked the following answer as correct as it helped me with solutions for the way I had currently implemented it. I'll probably use this approach when i try something like this again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update two parameters, then this will be enough :

```
window.location.search = '?name=' + person + '&scene=' + readCookie("scene");
```

That is, you dont need to add `scene.html`

```
"window.location.search" is the content of the current url after '?'.
```

So when you assign it with another value, the browser will update it and send request to server.